# Correct use of subprocess.Popen to issue a command via SSH

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

Other posts touch on the topic but I'm still not clear as to why this works:

```
command = "echo /sbin/poweroff | ssh admin@" + address
shutcmd = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

and this doesn't work:

```
 shutcmd = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "/sbin/poweroff" "|" "ssh", "admin@",address], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

How would you do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `|` is shell syntax and semantics.

You would simulate this by doing:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

user = "root"
host = "1.2.3.4"

p = Popen(
    ["ssh", "{}@{}".format(user, host)],
    stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT
)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate("/sbin/poweroff\n")
```

However it's even simpler to just issue the command itself as an argument to `ssh`:

```
p = Popen(
    ["ssh", "{}@{}".format(user, host), "/sbin/poweroff"],
)
p.wait()
```

As an aside; the reason your first example works at all is because of `shell=True`. A shell is involved to run your "piece of shell" so therefore the new shell that is spawned has it's own set of fd triples for stdin, stdout and stderr; so `echo | ssh` work.

See: [Pipeline (UNIX)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)

Comment: Do you really need the `p.wait()`? My understanding is that `communicate` will wait for the subprocess to finish. You can also get a deadlock with `wait` and `PIPE` used together, although in this case since you first `communicate` you should flush the output buffer.

Comment: @EricAppelt In the first or 2nd example? I've fixed the first.

Comment: Ok, the first looks good now, but the second is concerning. I have gotten bitten by this deadlock issue before, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects. I think that in the second example you should set `stdout=None, stderr=None` since you will not read it, and then it is safe to wait. The process has to actually produce a few kB of output in order to trigger the deadlock.

Comment: @EricAppelt Good point; and done. I believe these "deadlocks" are "buffering" issues which can be overcome with a bit of tweaking IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the command to run to ssh, you don't have to pipe into it.

Try

```
shutcmd = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'admin@' + address, '/sbin/poweroff'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```